# How do I save (persist) class objects that include other classes with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, persistent-storage

I'm having a little trouble trying to wrap my head around saving data. I know at the very least that if I were to have a simple class with primitive types then I'd only need the NSCoding (encoder and decoder). But I have a main class that has 2 other objects of the same class and I'm not too sure how to persist it.

Example of the main class:

```
class MainClass {
  var name: String
  var description: String
  var objectA: CustomClass
  var objectB: CustomClass
  ...
}
```

Would I have to implement the same encoding as I do with the main class? Make it serializable? How would I go to save that?

Comment: did you try my answer?, did my answer solve your problem?, please let me know about it

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `NSCoding` in your contained classes and then you can do this

```
class MainClass {
  var name: String
  var description: String
  var objectA: CustomClass
  var objectB: CustomClass

   required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init()
         if let decodedObjectA = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "objectA") as? CustomClass{
             self.objectA = decodedObjectA
         }
        if let decodedObjectB = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "objectB") as? CustomClass{
             self.objectB = decodedObjectB
         }


    }
}

//MARK: NSCoding
extension MainClass : NSCoding
{
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.objectA, forKey: "objectA")
        aCoder.encode(self.objectB, forKey: "objectB")
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you